# Is WCF Service EntitySetRights.AllRead Secure?

Tags: security, authentication, devexpress, odata, wcf-security

I have the following code inside MyDataService.svc.cs (This is an example from DevExpress):

```
namespace MyDataService {

    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]

    [JSONPSupportBehavior]
    public class DataService : DataService<TestDataEntities>, IServiceProvider {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config) {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
            if (serviceType == typeof(IDataServiceStreamProvider)) {
                return new ImageStreamProvider();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args) {
            CustomBasicAuth.Authenticate(HttpContext.Current);
            if (HttpContext.Current.User == null)
                throw new DataServiceException(401, "Invalid login or password");
            base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
        }
    }
}
```

So while this is will check the Entity for a username and password, how safe is it that `config.SetEntitySetAccessRule` is set to `AllRead`. Wouldn't someone just be able to see this information on a url such as www.website.com/MyDataService.svc/Customer (where Customer is the table). If this is not so can someone please fill in the conceptual gap I am facing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that all entities will be returned when queried  - AllRead just disallows insert updates and deletes.

You will need to use [Query Interceptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx) to add your logic to restrict users to the set of data they have permission to view, for example adding a check user id to the query.